# Change the image size of one image within a list

Tags: html, css

So I'm creating a website and have run into a little problem in relation to lists. I'm aiming to make a specific image within the list slightly bigger as it appears smaller in relation to the others.

Here's an image for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hd6kh.jpg

In order to stack the 3 images on top and below, I have created two separate lists for the three at the top and the three at the bottom. This is where I believe the issue lies.

I have tried to use the following css code to solve the issue (note I have used 2px to make the outcome obvious)

```
.white-container ul li:nth-child(3) img {
    width: 2px;
}
```

This gives the following result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yU2xu.jpg

The HTML code is here:

```
<div class="white-container">
        <div class="container">
            <div>
                <ul class="firstthree">
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/brush.svg" class="brush" alt="brush">
                        <p class="brush">Graphic Design</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/wand.svg" class="wand" alt="wand">
                        <p class="wand">UI Design</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/code.svg" class="code" alt="code">
                        <p class="code">Front-end Dev</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div>
                <ul class="secondthree">
                <li>
                    <img src="images/settings.svg" class="settings" alt="settings">
                    <p class="settings">Back-end Dev</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="images/database.svg" class="database" alt="databases">
                    <p class = "database">Databases</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="images/mobile.svg" class="mobile" alt="mobile">
                    <p class="mobile">Mobile Devices</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Obviously I do not want the bottom right image to change. I am at a loss of what else to try. I have tried using

```
.white-container ul firstthree li:nth-child(3) img {
```

which i thought would work but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like what you really want here is a grid of same-sized cells, rather than two lists. And you want the text always at the bottom of the grid cell, and the image centered in the remaining space. How you implement it is another concern, but do I get the intent correctly ?

Comment: @Touffy yes this is what I'm trying to achieve and I used the two list method to implement this. I'm unsure how I would implement a grid of cells into the code!

Answer (score 0):

The first step will be to merge your two lists into one, because semantically they should be.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="images/brush.svg" alt="brush">
        <p>Graphic Design</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="images/wand.svg" alt="wand">
        <p>UI Design</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="images/code.svg" alt="code">
        <p>Front-end Dev</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="images/settings.svg" alt="settings">
        <p>Back-end Dev</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="images/database.svg" alt="databases">
        <p>Databases</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="images/mobile.svg" alt="mobile">
        <p>Mobile Devices</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And then tell the browser to *display* the list as a grid.

```
ul {
    display: grid;
    list-style: none;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

Then you can use flex inside each cell to arrange the items vertically (`ul > li { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }`). I'll leave the rest to you.